# How can I run a cleanup script on virtualenv `deactivate`?

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtualenv

Via `autoenv`, whenever I `cd` into a directory with a `.env` file, I automatically activate my python virtual environment and set some environment variables. This `.env` file by essence is a setup script.

```
# /absolute/path/to/project/.env
source /absolute/path/to/project/.venv/bin/activate

export ENV_VAR_1="foo"
export ENV_VAR_2="bar"
```

But when I'm done working on my project and I type `deactivate`

- I *expect* these environment variables to vanish.
- In *reality*, these environment variables persist.

Is there a clean way for me to run a teardown script when I call `deactivate` that does some project clean up when I'm done for the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `activate` script, there is a `deactivate` block in which you can unset the variables:

```
deactivate () {
    # ...
    unset ENV_VAR_1
    unset ENV_VAR_2
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, do you think appending my cleanup to this function be the only way to go about this? I see how this is effective, but it feels hacky.

Comment: Nah, the activate script is exactly where all you your custom activation/deactivation logic goes. If it is a lot of code, you can move it to a separate script and call it from here.

Comment: Neato! So I should probably set those variables in the activate script rather than the .env file then. Right?

Comment: I've always put all in there. Single location :)

Comment: Edge Scenario. I'm going to be dynamically generating permutations of my project with a script at times. I don't wan't to manipulate the activate script by hand. How can I integrate these changes to the activation file via shell script?